# Rearranging elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list which contains some items. I want to rearrange them as follows:

- `product_name` should be the first element
- `items` starting with *image* should be the last (also, they should be sorted)
- the rest of the items should come in between, in no particular order.

**Misc**: There's only one (and always a) `product_name` in my list and the items inside are arranged in no particular order (that said, the order of the items is random - I just gave an example). Also, the list contains unique `items`.

The below does its job, but it seems a bit verbose and inefficient. I'm sure there's a way to do this in a single for loop but I kinda have a brainfart now. Is there an easier way to achieve the following?

```
def rearrange(header):
    final = ['product_name']
    images = sorted([item for item in header if item.startswith('image')])

    for item in header:
        if item != 'product_name' and not item.startswith('image'):
            final.append(item)

    final += images
    return final


header = [
    'word2',
    'image_4',
    'word1',
    'product_name',
    'image_3',
    'image_1',
    'image_5',
    'word3',
    'image_6',
    'image_2',
]

print(rearrange(header))
```

Result:

> ```
> ['product_name', 'word2', 'word1', 'word3', 'image_1', 'image_2', 'image_3', 'image_4', 'image_5', 'image_6']
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `key` keyword of the `sorted` builtin:

```
 sorted(header, key=lambda x: (x.startswith('image') + (x != 'product_name'), x))
```

Result:

```
['product_name', 'word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'image_1', 'image_2', 'image_3', 'image_4', 'image_5', 'image_6']
```

Comment: I was sure there's a solution using `sorted()`. Looks very neat and simple, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
header = [
'word2',
'image_4',
'word1',
'product_name',
'image_3',
'image_1',
'image_5',
'word3',
'image_6',
'image_2',
]
final_results = ['product_name']+[i for i in header if i != 'product_name' and not i.startswith('image')]+sorted([i for i in header if i.startswith('image')])
```

Output:

```
['product_name', 'word2', 'word1', 'word3', 'image_1', 'image_2', 'image_3', 'image_4', 'image_5', 'image_6']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could re-use the technique you used for building the images list to build a non-images list. Since you don't need it sorted leave that off, but remember to exclude product_name as well. Then glue them together with += like you have. No 'for' loop needed.

```
def rearrange(header):
    final = ['product_name']
    images = sorted([item for item in header if item.startswith('image')])
    non_images = [item for item in header if not item.startswith('image') and item !='product_name']

    retval = final
    retval += non_images
    retval += images
    return retval
```